# 行列×行列の掛け算

Tags: python, 行列

下記の積関数を拡張し，行列×ベクトルと行列×行列の掛け算を行うコードを書きたいのですが，うまくできません....
行列×ベクトルはうまく実行できているのですが....
またその際，掛ける側がベクトルか行列かで計算を変える必要があります。
分かるかたお教えいただければ幸いです。

```
from operator import mul

class Vector:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.num = args

    def out(self):
        print(self.num)

class Matrix:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.matrix = args

  def __mul__(self, tensor):
    if isinstance(tensor, Vector):
      print(Vector(*[sum([col*tensor.num[i] for i, col in enumerate(row)]) for row in self.matrix]))
      return Vector(*[sum([col*tensor.num[i] for i, col in enumerate(row)]) for row in self.matrix])
    elif isinstance(tensor, Matrix):
      print([[sum(map(mul, row, col)) for col in zip(*self.matrix)] for row in tensor.matrix])
      return [[sum(map(mul, row, col)) for col in zip(*self.matrix)] for row in tensor.matrix]
    else:
      raise TypeError('Not a Vector or Matrix instance')



x = Vector(1,8,4)

A = Matrix([1,2,3],
           [3,-2,1])
y = A * x

y.out()

#単位行列
I = Matrix([1,0,0],
           [0,1,0],
           [0,0,1])

y = I * x
y.out()

A = Matrix([0,1],
           [2,3],
           [4,5])

B = Matrix([0,1,2,3],
           [4,5,6,7])

y = A * B
print(y.matrix)
```

実行結果1(__mul__内のprint無し)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実行結果2(計算が正しいか確認するため__mul__内にprintを入れた)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

以下はサンプル実装です。参考にして下さい。

```py
class Vector:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.vector = args

  def out(self):
    print(self.vector)

class Matrix:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.matrix = args

  def __mul__(self, tensor):
    if isinstance(tensor, Vector):
      return Vector(
        *[sum(col*tensor.vector[i] for i, col in enumerate(row))
          for row in self.matrix])
    elif isinstance(tensor, Matrix):
      return Matrix(
        *[[sum(a*b for a, b in zip(x, y)) for y in zip(*tensor.matrix)]
          for x in self.matrix])
    else:
      raise TypeError('Not a Vector or Matrix instance')

  def out(self):
    print(self.matrix)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = Vector(1, 8, 4)
  A = Matrix(
    [1,  2, 3],
    [3, -2, 1],
  )

  # 行列×ベクトル
  y = A * x
  y.out()

  # 単位行列
  I = Matrix(
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
  )

  # 行列×ベクトル
  y = I * x
  y.out()

  # 行列×行列
  A = Matrix(
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
  )

  B = Matrix(
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7],
  )

  y = A * B
  y.out()
```

**実行結果**

```
(29, -9)
(1, 8, 4)
([4, 5, 6, 7], [12, 17, 22, 27], [20, 29, 38, 47])
```

> 掛ける側がベクトルか行列かで計算を変える必要があります。

`isinstance()` で `Vector` か `Matrix` 型かを判定して処理を切り替えてみてはどうでしょうか。

```
class Matrix:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.matrix = args

  def __mul__(self, tensor):
    if isinstance(tensor, Vector):
      return Vector(*[sum([col*tensor.num[i] for i, col in enumerate(row)]) for row in self.matrix])
    elif isinstance(tensor, Matrix):
      return ...
    else:
      raise TypeError('Not a Vector or Matrix instance')
```

Comment: サポートいただき誠にありがとうございます！
お助言いただいたコードに変更して実行したのですが，以下の問題が発生しました
１．計算後の行列がprintできない
１．計算結果が正しくない

Comment: 計算結果を `Matrix` 型に変換する必要があります。`return Matrix(*[[sum(map(mul, row, col)) for col in zip(*self.matrix)] for row in tensor.matrix])`

Comment: なるほど....
完全に理解できました。
本当にありがとうございます....